# ANT Build - Signed APK Signature Issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant, build.xml

When I build with `Export Signed Application Package` in Eclipse, and I use the keystore I created the first time, it works.

Now I'm trying to use ANT to build the release APK (not debug), but, when I try to install the new APK on my real phone (not emulator), it trhows `an existing package by the same name with a conflicting signature` and I can't install.

Of course, this means that the signature is incorrect, or something simialar with the password.

This is the info I put in local.propeties

```
sdk.dir=D:\\Documents\\Applications\\Android SDK

key.store=D:\\Projects\\myProject\\signature_key
key.alias=two words
key.store.password=PasswordUsing$and%
key.alias.password=PasswordUsing$and%
```

Yes. The key.alias has 2 words (my mistake, but it's late now)

**1) Is the format valid? Should I use quotes for the alias? Should I escape $ or % characters in the password?**

**2) What format should I use in local.properties to make the keystore/password be valid?**

**3) Is there something I'm missing?**

Comment: Are you using netbeans or why are you using ant?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse to build Android Apps (like stated in the tags)

Comment: If the signature was incorrect in your configuration file, I don't think the project would get signed actually.  I think your configuration might be fine (change the password and see if it still finishes or if it throws an error).

Comment: If I change the password I get `Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect: Password verification failed`. With the right password, BUILD SUCCESSFUL, but it doesn't work

Comment: This may be a silly question, but did your first uninstall the app that was signed with the debug key? Or is your phone running a previous release build?

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal behaviour *if* you have previously loaded the debug version of your app on your phone. The OS recognises the package as being already present and refuses to install the release version which has been signed with a different key.

You must uninstall the debug version first, then install the release one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to deploy your app to the Play Store, you will need to create your own keystore (not re-use the debug keystore the tools use to build your app by default).

Export your project using the Export Wizard (right-click on the project, Android, Export...)

When going through this Wizard, there is a selection to generate a keystore, go through that, and save the resulting keystore files (somewhere safe, if you lose these, you will NEVER be able to deploy your app again to the Play Store).

I think you should skip ANT, and instead use the Wizard GUI.

Also - keep in mind if you deploy a debug build, you will need to uninstall it, before deploying your officially signed APK.

Comment: I'm not using the debug keystore.
I'm referencing, in local.properties the same keystore I used with the wizard, but I think the format is not ok.

Comment: Will check my projects ant file - you should still use the Wizard I think.

Comment: I want to use ANT to avoid using the wizard. I want to update 100 apps, so you will understand my perspective when I want to solve this simple problem. Thanks for checking

Comment: I checked my project, and don't have that file.  Sorry - I would Google that (sure you have) - good luck.